# What is the difference between {{}} and [[]] in the template data binding in Polymer?

Tags: polymer

I sometimes come across `{{}}` syntax and sometimes `[[]]` in the **template data binding**. I am rather sure `[[]]` usage, w*hich is referring the properties in the component*,but what does `{{}}` do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double Brackets \[\[ \]\] vs Double Braces {{ }} in Polymer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195313/double-brackets-vs-double-braces-in-polymer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding

> Binding annotation
>     Text surrounded by double curly bracket (`{{ }}`) or double square bracket (`[[ ]]`) delimiters. Identifies the host data being bound.
>   Compound binding
>     A string literal containing one or more binding annotations.
>
> Whether data flow goes down from host to target, up from target to host, or both ways is controlled by the type of binding annotation and
>   the configuration of the target property.
>
> - Double-curly brackets (`}`) support both upward and downward data flow.
> - Double square brackets (`[[ ]]`) are *one-way*, and support only only downward data flow.